# C# SerialPort DataReceived event randomly lags

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have a device (a scale controller) that blindly sends frames on a serial port. No reply needed. Using a serial terminal client (Putty) I can see 1 frame per second being transmitted, and this is very consistent.

Now, I made this little bit of code:

```
mSerialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
mSerialPort.DataReceived += SerialPort_DataReceived;
mSerialPort.ReadTimeout = 1000;

mSerialPort.Open();

private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string data = mSerialPort.ReadExisting();
    this.OnDataReceived(data);
}
```

Sometimes this works fine and `SerialPort_DataReceived` is called as expected. However, it happens quite often and randomly that the event is not triggered for several seconds (like 5 seconds, sometimes more), and then, all of a suddent it is triggered with all the stacked frame data in one call.

I tried setting the handshaking to RequestToSend with no change. Also, it is not the `ReadExisting()` method that hangs. It's actually the event that stops triggering.

I've read threads about the event not firing at all or causing lag when closing, but nothing helped. I think DataReceived triggers in a seperate thread. Is there anything that could slow down that thread, or even pause it?

Any other idea?

Comment: Sure, the event runs on a threadpool thread.  If it has a big backlog then it can take a while.  Use the debugger's Debug > Windows > Threads window to diagnose, watch out for running tp threads that take too long to get their job done.  Threadpool.SetMaxThreads() is a quick a very dirty workaround.

Comment: I had another thread running at the same time. I removed it and the lag is gone. Looks like you're right. You can make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you very much!